# How to split pandas data frame by repeating rows?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the df like this:

```
1   a   12
2   a   3
3   b   45
4   b   34
5   b   23
```

and I need to split it to two df like this:

```
1   a   12
2   a   3
```

and

```
3   b   45
4   b   34
5   b   23
```

Someone know any reasonable quick way?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
d = {x : y for x , y in df.groupby('col')}
```